# Discrete logarithm algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I've often seen that the discrete logarithm is a hard problem. However, I don't quite see how this could be. It seems to me that a regular binary search would do just fine to serve this purpose. For example,

```c
binary_search(base, left, right, target) {
    if (pow(base, left) == target) 
        return left;
    if (pow(base, right) == target)
        return right;
    if (pow(base, (left + right) / 2) < target)
        return binary_search(base, (left + right) / 2, right, target);
    else
        return binary_search(base, left, (left + right) / 2, target);
}   

log(base, number) {
    left = 1;
    right = 2;
    while(pow(base, p) < number) {
        left = right;
        right *= 2;
    }
    return binary_search(base, left, right, number);
}
```

If the naive implementation of just incrementing `p` until `pow(base, p)` is O(n), then surely this binary search is O(log(n) ^2).

Or do I not understand how this algorithm is measured?

Edit: I don't usually write binary searches, so if there's some trivial implementation error, kindly just ignore it or edit in a fix.

Comment: What’s the complexity of `pow`?

Comment: @JoshLee: Logarithmic in the power, at most.

Comment: Try this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes that a < b implies pow(base, a) < pow(base, b).

This is true for natural numbers, but it won't work in a finite cyclic group (when 'pow' is calculated modulo some number).

Comment: That quite clearly explains the discrepancy between my intuition and the truth- I hadn't considered such.